# Simple conversation wall

Tags: views

I want to create a simple wall, where user can post some text, and other users can reply on it. It can be done without ajax or with. I have made few modules before, but now  i am stack with this part, how to create a page(which i can link into menu) on which i can post message, and then watch the list of this conversations+comments, should i use Views module? any examples would be the way.

here is example of that wall,  [image: example]

Comment: Sounds like a single node with comments enabled would do the trick...any reason why that wouldn't work?

Comment: god damn dude) u made my day , thank you, i am new to drupal, yeas node without body with comments!

Comment: @Clive That would be an answer, if you also explain how to get hierarchical comments. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out http://drupal.org/project/facebook_status.
Also if ur on D7 then https://drupal.org/project/statuses